# Wordpress Contact Form 7 plugin taking too long after submitting a form

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Wordpress Contact Form 7 plugin taking too long after i click submit :

i am getting email but it almost take 1 minute to complete a ajax request

http://192.241.244.250/health-information-exchange-software-demo/

Comment: What does the developer console say? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it dont show any error just taking 1 min to change ajax stage from pending to success @disinfor

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the form is working correctly now but looks like you're having some css issues